# Inequality between $2$ random variables with normal distribution

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ are random variables with the following distribution:
$$X \sim  N(0, \sigma^2_X),Y \sim  N(0, \sigma^2_Y)$$

I need to calculate the following probability:
$$\mathrm{Pr} [X > Y] = ?$$

Can anyone help?

Comment: You cannot say anything unless you know the **joint** distribution of $(X,Y)$. Are $X$ and $Y$ supposed to be independent ?

Comment: Hint: integrate the probability of $(X,Y)$ over the domain $X>Y$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Gabriel Romon, the problem cannot be solved until we know the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$. Under the additional assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, here is a simple trick:

Standardize both variables by introducing $Z_1 = X/\sigma_X$ and $Z_2 = Y/\sigma_Y$. Then $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent standard normal variables. Now write

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Pr}[X > Y]
&= \mathrm{Pr}[X - Y > 0] \\
&= \mathrm{Pr}[\sigma_X Z_1 - \sigma_Y Z_2 > 0] \\
&= \mathrm{Pr}[(\sigma_X, -\sigma_Y) \cdot (Z_1, Z_2) > 0] \\
&= \mathrm{Pr}[(Z_1, Z_2) \in H],
\end{align*}

where $\cdot$ is the dot product and

$$ H = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : (\sigma_X, -\sigma_Y) \cdot (x, y) > 0 \} $$

is the half-plane divided by the line $\sigma_Y x + \sigma_X y = 0$. Then we invoke the fact that the distribution of $(Z_1, Z_2)$ is invariant under rotations. In particular, $(Z_1, Z_2)$ assumes any possible directions in the plane uniformly likely. From this, we get

$$ \mathrm{Pr}[(Z_1, Z_2) \in H] = \frac{1}{2}. $$